# Need guidance while saving div in a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mysql, html

I have a parent container in which user add dynamically text , images and user able drag them inside container . Now i want to save this container as it is in a mysql database. Well I have tried to save in mysql by taking innerhtml of my contianer wrraper it saves. but that thing take care of text only and images when they are on the same location . What if I delete the image or remove it from original location then image wont display. Can you guys help me how to achive this .

Regards
Manoj

Comment: where do you get the images from? Do you use the images stored on a path on the webserver?

Comment: I provided the functionality of upload image in web. In that it saves on a temp location of a webserver and later when user log out then with help of script we delete the image

Comment: So the div contain only temporary data. What happens when user login again?

Comment: Actually I want that suppose user added couple of images and texts in a div. Now I want to give save button by which user when comes later can see its last work preview and If he wants to do any modification he do and again save it.

Comment: Why do you delete the image from temp folder? If you don't delete them the image would be available to the user when he/she login again.

Comment: but it has drawback. If user is in limited number then its ok.What if there is lots of users. Then we have to save each image.Thats why we drop out that plan.In this we have manage give each image a unique number or name also otherwise it will overwrite.

Comment: Well when the images are not persisted they will be displayed as well when the user login again. In short you can show something which no longer exists. As per your requirement you would need to persist the image.

Comment: Yes. I am seeking the best way to immplement this.

Comment: You could save the images as base64 encoded strings in the database. This can be loaded fairly quickly, and you won't have to clog up your temp-folder. It will, of course, become a rather big table, so you may need to put limits on the size of the image, and the amount of images per user.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the images in the database and then use a php/asp.net/coldfusion/ruby/etc script that reports itself as the MIME type of the image and echos the data from the database out and put that php script in your image tag. Just store the image and the mime type in the database and do something like this.

```
$laImage = getImageDataFromDatabase();
header('Content-type: ' . $laImage['img_mimetype']);
echo($laImage['img_data']);
```